# TemplateBinding a GradientStop Offset

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to bind a GradientStop Offset in order to display some sort of progress bar inside an Ellipse. 
The CustomControl is a button and if possible I'd like to keep it that way.
Of course there are several Dependency Properties and OffsetProgress is one of them.

**Is it possible to TemplateBind a GradientStop Offset?**

*Languages are C# XAML WPF.*

Here's the code if anyone thinks it can be useful:

```
<Ellipse Stroke="Black"
     StrokeThickness="1"
     Stretch="Uniform">
<Ellipse.Fill>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0"
                         StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=Background.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                      Offset="{TemplateBinding OffsetProgress}" /> <!-- Not Working -->
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF"
                      Offset="0.5" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Ellipse.Fill>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error, just not working (same as offset = 0).

Comment: Have you just tried `<GradientStop Offset="{Binding Path=OffsetProgress, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Color="{Binding Path=Background.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />` or the RelativeSource equivalent?

Comment: Haha. Hum. Yeah you're right. Why didn't I think of this?
I foolishly belived that TemplatedParent was limited to actual properties of the parent (here: the button properties).

Can't vote you for some reason.